# I want to check that a certain list follows a pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm building a program that needs to have and input from the user where the user introduces a sequence of numbers separated with commas, example: 1,2,3,4.

The sequence can be any amount of numbers, have any number in it and have spaces in between, the only thing that has to be followed is that there's a number then a coma and maybe in between somewhere a space

I've done this until now

```
`sec=input("Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:")

com = 0
num = 1
numlist=[]

for x in sec:
    if x == "," or x==" ":
        None
    else:
        try:
            numlist.append(int(x))
        except:
            print("Please just insert numbers and commas")

    if x == ",":
        com+=1
    elif x == " ":
        None
    else:
        num+=1

if com <= num and (com>(num-3)):

    print(numlist)
    print(tuple(numlist))
else:
    print("Please enter a comma between the numbers")`
```

The only thing I'm missing is to check the that the sequence is number comma number comma etc...

Because with the code I have actually, you can introduce Number comma comma Number and it would work

1, 2, ,3 5

I was expecting this: Please enter a comma between the numbers

Got this

Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:1, 2, ,3 5
[1, 2, 3, 5]
(1, 2, 3, 5)

Comment: Why not just parse the users input with a csv parser?

Comment: I'm new to python to I'm just practicing exercises and all that, so I'm not using any file as input just the terminal input

Comment: do you need the different responses of "Please just insert numbers and commas" and "Please enter a comma between the numbers" or is just rejecting all invalid strings fine.

Comment: Thing is needs to be done as if the user doesn't really follow instruction so even if you say enter enter a number a comma, the user will input whatever he wants

Comment: at the moment on invalid inputs the code will output a statement like "please enter a comma  between the numbers" and then it will still output a num list at the end. Do you instead want it to keep on looping only output the numlist once the input is valid?

Comment: instead of `None` better use `pass` if you don't want to perform anything inside a block. If you want to check a variable against different values, better use `if x in (",", " "):`.  You can also compare two inequalities at the same time instead of using an and: `if (num-3) < com <= num:`

Comment: Okay I've changed a bit so now it wont go through if it has letters thing is that if you try the following answer 1,2,,3 4 it will go through and show this Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:1,2,,3 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
(1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: the simplest start is to use the built in `split()` method on strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression `re` to match the string whether it follows your pattern or not. For example, if your requirement is: Any string where there is a single comma `,` between `digits`, can have multiple spaces in between and the string should end with a number or space (I am assuming you don't want to end with a comma), you can use below expression :

```
^(\s*\d+\s*\,)*(\s*\d+\s*)$
```

If you are new to regular expressions, see below explanation:

In above expression,

- `(\s*\d+\s*\,)`, means multiple spaces `\s*` (even 0)
- Followed by one or more digit `\d+`
- Followed by again multiple spaces `\s*`
- Ending with a comma `\,`.
- The `*` after this group means above pattern can repeat zero or more time
- The last group `(\s*\d+\s*)` means a digit with leading and trailing spaces. Your string should end with this pattern.

Below is the full code that may help you:

```
import re

sec=input("Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:")
# Check if your string matches your pattern
if re.match(r'^(\s*\d+\s*\,)*(\s*\d+\s*)$', sec):

    # Split the string from comma 
    # str.split("pattern") converts your string into a string of list
    # "1, 2, 4".split(",") -> ["1 ", "2 ", "4"]
    # "1@@ 2@@ abcd".split("@@") -> ["1 ", "2 ", "abcd"]
    arr = sec.split(",")
    
    # For each element in arr, use int() function
    # map(function, iterable): applies given function on each element
    # of the iterator. Here, we want to apply int() on each element
    numlist = list(map(int, arr))

    print(numlist)
    print(tuple(numlist))

# Otherwise ask user to input proper string
else:
    print("Please enter a comma between the numbers")
```

Hope it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if you could explain the split part and what's map used for, as I just started with python

Comment: @Desayin added more explanation. But still I would suggest you to go through python documentation to understand more about these functions.

Answer (score 2):

The normal and simplest way to solve this problem would be to use regular expressions as Mukul Bindal's answer shows.

Another approach is to use `str.split` and check that the strings in the output list are not empty or contain only spaces (two consecutive commas) and can be parsed to `int`, something like:

```
sec = input("Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:")

numlist = []
for sub in sec.split(","):
    if sub:
        try:
            num = int(sub)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid character or a comma was expected")
            break
        finally:
            numlist.append(num)
    else:
        print("A number was expected")
        break
else:
    print(numlist)
```

However, if you want for curiosity or learning purposes to validate and parse the string using only conditionals and a loop as you pose in your question, you can do it, for example, using a state variable:

```
sec = input("Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:")

numlist = []
start_num_idx = 0

state = "waiting number"
for i, char in enumerate(sec):
    if char == " ":
        if state == "reading number":
            numlist.append(int(sec[start_num_idx: i + 1]))
            state = "waiting comma"
    elif char == ",":
        if state == "reading number":
            numlist.append(int(sec[start_num_idx: i]))
        elif state == "waiting number":
            print(f"Unexpected comma not preceded by number at index {i}")
            break
        state = "waiting number"

    elif char in "0123456789":
        if state == "waiting number":
            state = "reading number"
            start_num_idx = i
        elif state == "waiting comma":
            print(f"Unexpected number not preceded by comma at index {i}")
            break
    else:
        print(f"Invalid character at index {i}: {char}")
        break
else:
    if state == "waiting number" and numlist:
        print("Final comma not followed by a number")
    else:
        if state == "reading number":
            numlist.append(int(sec[start_num_idx: i + 1]))
        if numlist:
            print(numlist)
        else:
            print("You have not entered any number")
```

The code can be simplified, but it is verbose on purpose.

> ```
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:   
> You have not entered any number
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:,45
> Unexpected comma not preceded by number at index 0
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:   , 45
> Unexpected comma not preceded by number at index 3
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:45
> [45]
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:    45
> [45]
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:45,
> Final comma not followed by a number
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:  45 ,  , 4
> Unexpected comma not preceded by number at index 8
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:45,,9
> Unexpected comma not preceded by number at index 3
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:45, 47 78, 5
> Unexpected number not preceded by comma at index 7
>
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:45, 13@3, 4
> Invalid character at index 6: @    
>  
> Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:  45  ,  9,8,9  ,7  
> [45, 9, 8, 9, 7]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The requirements are a bit unclear but here is an attempt that only accepts valid answers with a while loop:

```
check = True
while check:
    numlist=[]
    sec=input("Please insert a sequence of numbers separated by commas:").replace(" ", "")
    check = False
    for i,x in enumerate(sec):
        if i%2==0:
            try:
                numlist.append(int(x))
            except:
                check = True
        elif x!=',':
            check = True
    
    
print(numlist)
print(tuple(numlist))
```